# Windows 7 Explorer folder listing defaults to tiny width

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

There have been some weird design decisions in Explorer to say the least. One of the worst of which for me is when I open a files folder location the filename column width is about 10% of available screen width. How do I change the default width? I constantly need to resize explorer's stupid default.

Comment: "when I open a file in it's folder location the folder listing width is about 10% of available screen width" - Are you talking about the column width? What does that have to do with opening a file? Can you provide a screenshot highlighting the problem?

Comment: good point. I edited to make it clearer - yes, talking about the column width. I have no idea how to set a sane default.

Answer (score 1):

If you get a folder looking the way you want it and then select Organize from the menu - and then folder options - then click the view tab and finally click the Apply to all Folders button. This view should then be the default.

These settings can be overridden however if you have already applied a view to a specific folder using the Organize - Properties - Customize - and then applying a view for a particular type of folder like pictues.

My standard view is the details view, group by type ascending and sort by name ascending - I find this the most practical for most general folders.